# Docker image build failed: go mod download: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/***/***?fields=scm: 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

Building of Docker image started to fail just now. It was working yesterday.

This is the error coming:

```
Step 14/31 : RUN go mod download
 ---> Running in 9dcd36a5e81b
go mod download: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/***/***?fields=scm: 404 Not Found
```

Note: `***` is replaced for workspace/project name and repository name due to privacy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the go version in the base image from `FROM golang:1.17.3-alpine as builder` to `FROM golang:1.17.8-alpine as builder` fixed the issue.